# Cybersource IOS SDK with PHP

Tags: ios, wordpress, woocommerce, cybersource

We need to integrate cybersource to an ios application, we found the SDK here: https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-ios-sdk and token generation is working too. I am not not sure how to process the token, can I do this from PHP in my server?

We are integrating with woocommerce on a wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you have the token you pass that to your server.

From the server you will want to process payments using the SOAP API.  You can build your own client - http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/SOAP_Toolkits/SOAP_toolkits.pdf.

Or use one of the pre-built ones that CyberSource provides (including PHP) - https://www.cybersource.com/developers/getting_started/integration_methods/simple_order_api/

Comment: How to get OTP screen using cyber source. The sample app helps to create the token. Once token is passed to server. How server can opt for one time password verification